# Can I open multiple debug consoles in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to open multiple debug consoles in xcode for the same debug session?
I'm kind of tired of scrolling back and forth when reading long traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind-of-possible.

It is possible to open one project in multiple xcode windows and open the debug console on each of them, effectively giving you multiple debug consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. You can always redirect NSLog output to the file (even when running in Simulator) and read that file in any text editor you prefer.